# Output specific key value in object for each element in array with jq for JSON

Tags: iteration, jq

I have an array:

```
[
    {
        "AssetId": 14462955,
        "Name": "Cultural Item"
    },
    {
        "AssetId": 114385498,
        "Name": "Redspybot"
    },
    {
        "AssetId": 29715011,
        "Name": "American Cowboy"
    },
    {
        "AssetId": 98253651,
        "Name": "Mahem"
    }
]
```

I would like to loop through each object in this array, and pick out the value of each key called `AssetId` and output it.
How would I do this using jq for the command line?

Comment: Please make it more clear whether it is a [jq] question or [jquery] question.  They are _not_ the same and should not be used together... Your question is completely ambiguous in how you tagged it and asked it.

Answer (score 105, accepted):

The command-line tool `jq` writes to STDOUT and/or STDERR.  If you want to write the .AssetId information to STDOUT, then one possibility would be as follows:

```
jq -r ".[] | .AssetId" input.json
```

Output:

```
14462955
114385498
29715011
98253651
```

A more robust incantation would be: `.[] | .AssetId?` but your choice will depend on what you want if there is no key named "AssetId".

Comment: Note: How would I send each one into a function?

Comment: After trying this, I found an error. It says unexpected string.

Comment: @ZimbabweElephant - please see update.  If you are still having problems, then please be more specific and/or create a new SO Q as appropriate.

Comment: @ZimbabweElephant - not sure what "function" you are referring to.   One that you create yourself in jq?

Comment: This just gives a string output. You can't put this in a bash for loop.

Comment: @Craig - There was nothing in the question about a bash for loop, but if someone wants to feed the selected values to a bash for loop, the usual way would be to use the idiom: .... | while read -r line ; do ... ; done

Comment: Shoot @peak, you're right. I was pulling my hair out today trying to figure out how to loop through a json array, and when I solved it, I decided to go back and post my answer in the places that didn't quite answer my question. This thread was not the right place to post. I'll remove my answer from this thread.

Answer (score 29):

You can also do it via this command.

```sh
jq ".[].AssetId" input.json
```

if array like be that which is in my case

```json
{  
   "resultCode":0,
   "resultMsg":"SUCCESS",
   "uniqueRefNo":"111222333",
   "list":[  
      {  
         "cardType":"CREDIT CARD",
         "isBusinessCard":"N",
         "memberName":"Bank A",
         "memberNo":10,
         "prefixNo":404591
      },
      {  
         "cardType":"DEBIT CARD",
         "isBusinessCard":"N",
         "memberName":"Bank A",
         "memberNo":10,
         "prefixNo":407814
      },
      {  
         "cardType":"CREDIT CARD",
         "isBusinessCard":"N",
         "memberName":"Bank A",
         "memberNo":10,
         "prefixNo":413226
      }
   ]
}
```

you can get the prefixNo with below jq command.

```sh
jq ".list[].prefixNo" input.json
```

For more specific case on array iterating on jq you can check [this blogpost](http://arjanvandergaag.nl/blog/wrestling-json-with-jq.html)

Answer (score 7):

you have a couple of choices to do the loop itself. you can apply peak's awesome answer and wrap a shell loop around it. replace echo with the script you want to run.

#### via xargs

```
$ jq -r ".[] | .AssetId" input.json | xargs -n1 echo  # this would print
14462955
114385498
29715011
98253651
```

#### via raw loop

```
$ for i in $(jq -r ".[] | .AssetId" input.json)
  do
    echo $i
  done
14462955
114385498
29715011
98253651
```

Answer (score 5):

An alternative using `map`:

```
jq "map ( .AssetId ) | .[]"
```

Answer (score 3):

For your case  `jq -r '.[].AssetId'` should work

You can also use online JQ Parser : https://jqplay.org/

[image]

If you want to loop through the each value then can use below  :

```
for i in $(echo $api_response | jq -r ".[].AssetId")
  do
    echo echo $i 
  done
```